# Angular JS - input value from another input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to bind the value of an `input` to the value of another `input`? The following is not working:

```
<input ng-model="val">
<input value="Hello {{val}}">
```

Comment: What is not working?  It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your simple use case you posted you can use dot notation.

Fiddle example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54zhB/1/)

```
<input ng-model="new.val">
<input value="Hello {{new.val}}">
```

By using dot.notation you avoid collision with scoping issues and conflict with global namespace. Not knowing all the variables involved this might have been the issue.

Anything $scope.val would interfere.

```
<input ng-model="val">
<input value="Hello {{val}}">
```

By using dot notation and deep linking you can avoid a lot of common issues.

Comment: The OPs code works as is.  What advantage to you get from using dot notation?

Comment: Added more explanation. With limited info I tried posting a common issue I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/7HxnM3O1UE1RxCCPvvJ0?p=preview

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.formatText = function() {
        return "Hello " + $scope.text;
    };

    $scope.$watch('text', function(newValue) {
        $scope.formatedText = "Hello "+ (newValue ? newValue : "");
    })
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="formatedText"/>
</body>
```

For more common way you can use $scope.$eval together with your own directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZ8J1JRXm4QW8ZKhbHJj?p=preview) with your code.

### js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.val = 'Guy';

  });
```

### html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <input ng-model="val">
    <input value="Hello {{val}}">
  </body>

</html>
```

*Note: you aren't required to add `val` to the controller unless you want to initialize its value.